# expected expression before ‘{’ token c program

Tags: c, syntax-error

I wrote following code I am solving a puzzle I when compiled this part of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{

int a[10],b[10],c[10];
int i,j,k,l;
 a[10]={"21","33","12","19","15","17","11","12","34","10"};
 b[10]={"10","15","9","13","16","21","15","32","29","7"};
 c[10]={"11","8","3","6","1","4","6","20","19","3"};

 l=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

for (i=0;i<=l;i++)
 {
 }
}
```

gives me error

```
array.c: In function ‘main’:
array.c:7:8: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
array.c:8:8: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
array.c:9:8: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

Why is the error coming here?

Comment: You're setting array element 10 to an array.

Comment: @Polynomial eleventh actually.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be */me dies of embarassment*

Comment: @Polynomial I am not clear when you say that I am setting array element 10 to an array.

Comment: @RegisteredUser It's actually the 11th element, as per what Let_Me_Be pointed out. The array `a` has 11 elements, indexed 0 through 10. If you set `a[10]`, you're setting the 11th element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's several problems in your code:

1. You should initialize your arrays in the same line you declare them
2. You must initialize them with array of numbers, not with array of c-strings:
3. You actually try to set value to 11'th element of the array.

Correct line of code will be:

```
int a[10] = {21,33,12,19,15,17,11,12,34,10};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the **eleventh** element of the array to an array.

Try this:

```
int a[10] = {21,33,12,19,15,17,11,12,34,10};
```

Comment: @juergend DAMNIT! I'm terrible today. Stop making me look silly :(

Answer (score 0):

- Type mismatch: You are setting character literal strings to an `int`s. This is a no-no.
- You are accessing one past the end of the array -- a classic off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

this is int array don' put qoutes for numbers

```
c[10]={11,8,3,6,1,4,6,20,19,3};
```